# how to create data frame from multiple files located in different subfolders

Tags: python, filesystems

I have a folder which contain several sub-folders(a,b and c), each sub-folder contains 5 files , each files contain a single column of data and can be treated as an array. I want to create a data frame that contain the mean, standard deviation and median of each file.
The data frame should contain the following columns: subfolder name, file name, mean, std, median

I was able to write the following code by using defaultdict and received the following output shape {'b': ([array1]),([array2]),([array3]),([array4]),([array5]),'c': [array([array1]),([array2]),([array3]),([array4]),([array5]),'a': [array([array1]),([array2]),([array3]),([array4]),([array5])

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

root = "/My data"

# Map labels (subdirectories of root) to data
data_per_label = defaultdict(list)

# Get all top-level directories within `root`
label_dirs = [name for name in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, name))]
#print(f"{label_dirs}")

# Loop over each label directory
for label in label_dirs:
    label_dir = os.path.join(root, label)
    # Loop over each filename in the label directory
    for filename in os.listdir(label_dir):
        # Take care to only look at .data files
        if filename.endswith(".data"):
            filepath = os.path.join(label_dir, filename)
            #print(f"{filename}_{label}")
            data = np.loadtxt(filepath)
            data_per_label[label].append(data)


print(data_per_label)
```

I then used the following code to transform the defaultdict into dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[k] + j for k,v in data_per_label.items() for j in v], columns=['#', 'Distribution', 'Sample_1', 'Sample_2', 'Sample_3', 'Sample_4', 'Sample_5'])
print(df)
```

but received an error

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('float64')) -> None
```

Will appreciate any insight one can give me on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "but something is still missing". What do you mean? What is your output? How does it differ from your expected output? Provide a few samples of the the .data files

Comment: this is the current output I received from the above code 'defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': ['Sample1', 'Sample3', 'Sample2', 'Sample4', 'Sample5'], 'c': ['Sample1', 'Sample3', 'Sample2', 'Sample4', 'Sample5'], 'a': ['Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3', 'Sample4', 'Sample5']})' . the data files are an array of numbers all in one column.